# Empty site list in android app

Tags: bug, android-app

**App version:** 1.0.2

### Step to reproduce this issue:

1. If you are logged in then logout from the app
2. Start app by using "Start using without an account..."
3. Logout again
4. Now check the navigation drawer/sliding menu

### Issue:

- Sliding menu gets empty site list

It seems like a black magic is getting done in android app :)

### Update:

1. I tried to reproduce this issue after Kasra's commment, was failed to reproduce at that time.
2. I tried to reproduce it while posting this update, able to reproduce it.

Now, its finally a black magic :)

[image]

Comment: After you log out again in step 3 is the app not sending you back to the login screen?

Comment: Nope its not, but it starting with the "loading stack exchange sites" screen and then it moves to this main activity with empty site list screen.

Comment: Hmm that's the root bug here, hitting logout at any point should send you back to the screen asking you to login or use anonymous mode. Good catch, thanks!

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi Welcome! Pls check updated portion above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of v1.0.83<sup>or somewhere before that</sup>, it's not reproducible anymore because the root bug has been fixed:

> hitting logout at any point should send you back to the screen asking you to login or use anonymous mode - [Kasra Rahjerdi](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217843/empty-site-list-in-android-app#comment706161_217843)